# Dynamically rendered SVG is not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have the following svg object which if I put in html page directly without using code(static) it renders properly.

but same svg content if I insert into my html page using JavaScript it is not showing and if I open it in firebug and inspect svg and try to edit svg tag, it displays.

What could be the problem

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"></rect>
</svg>
```

I am adding svg dynamically using below code, here container will be my div which is there under body

```
        viewPort = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg');

        viewPort.setAttribute('height', 100);

        viewPort.setAttribute('width', 100);

        container.innerHTML = '';

        container.appendChild(viewPort);
```

After this I am adding rect inside this using

```
            boardElement = document.createElement('rect');

            boardElement.setAttribute('width', '100');

            boardElement.setAttribute('height', '100');

            boardElement.setAttribute('y', '1');

            boardElement.setAttribute('x', '1');

            boardElement.setAttribute('style', "fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)");


viewPort.appendChild(boardElement);
```

Comment: How did you create the SVG and how do you insert it to the document?

Comment: Like Sirko said, showing us directly where the problem is would help us :) Maybe showing us the javscript part that generates that svg?

Comment: I have edited code and added code about how I am adding svg dynamically.

Comment: Instead of adding code excerpts here, you can use http://jsbin.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ to reproduce your problem 1:1 with actual environment. That also helps us to easier debug it.

Comment: Thanks Surely I will make use jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net from next time, My problem got resolved now

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The element `boardElement` should be declared like so

`boardElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");`

Comment: This solved my problem, but I don't understand why it is like this. Because both the time rendered html code is same(source html).

Comment: I read on this issue and it explained why :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173217/createelement-vs-createelementns . Happy coding

Answer (score -1):

I confirm that the NS should be set for every element

document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path')