# Dynamically created SVG is rendered into HTML but not displayed properly

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am creating an SVG element dynamically and appending it to another element in the page.
The page displays the SVG element that is part of the HTML DOM written in the file, but it does not display the dynamically created one from Javascript.

I examined the rendered HTML output and found no difference between the dynamically created SVG and the one specified in the HTML file.

```js
var out = document.getElementById("output");
var svg = document.createElement("svg");
svg.setAttribute("width",50);
svg.setAttribute("height",50);
svg.setAttribute("style","background-color:#bada55");
svg.innerHTML = "why is this not displayed as SVG?";
out.appendChild(svg);
```

```html
<div id="output">
  <svg width="50" height="50" style="background-color:beige">This one is OK</svg>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

## Edit:

PS: I am using Chrome, and the way I see the output is: The beige SVG is rendered correctly, with no text inside it.
The green SVG (dynamically created) appears as if it was a `<span>` with the text appearing inside it.

Here is an image of what I see:
[image: Here is the expected output and what I am currently seeing]

And here is the rendered HTML:

```
<div id="output">
  <svg width="50" height="50" style="background-color:beige">This one is OK</svg>
  <svg width="50" height="50" style="background-color:#bada55">why is this not displayed as SVG?</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mamun aside from the styling colors, made it different for the purpose of the question

Comment: @Mamun I added the rendered HTML

Comment: With the code you have, how you want the second svg to be rendered?

Comment: The output should be two squares, one beige and one green. I am seeing the first beige square, but the other one is a green rectangle with text inside it @Mamun

Comment: What is the problem here? does height and width bother you?

Comment: @NarendraMongiya I added an image of the output I see. The green SVG appears AS IF it was a span

Comment: you need to use `createElementNS` and `setAttributeNS` where **NS** stands for namespace

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173217/createelement-vs-createelementns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) and that will solve your problem.

```js
var out = document.getElementById("output");
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svg.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#bada55');
svg.setAttribute('width', '50');
svg.setAttribute('height', '50');
svg.innerHTML = "why is this not displayed as SVG?";
svg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");

out.appendChild(svg);
```

```html
<div id="output">
  <svg width="50" height="50" style="background-color:beige">This one is OK</svg>
</div>
```