# SVG appended to DOM with JS but not visually rendering

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to create an SVG shape and append it to an element in my DOM.

The following JS appends the `<svg>` to the intended node, but doesn't render a purple background on the page:

```js
const svgBox = document.createElement("svg");
svgBox.setAttribute('height', 150);
svgBox.setAttribute('width', 800);
svgBox.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:purple;');
const div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];  // this does exist
div.appendChild(svgBox);
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q7mpjkr6/2/) showing the equivalent HTML that does work (if I comment the  tag back in) but the above JS not working. I've stripped this down from a more complex use case and have demonstrated to myself I'm missing some crucial basic display principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SVG is a namespaced element, so you have to use `createElementNS` instead of `createElement` - to understand why check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173217/createelement-vs-createelementns)

Here is a working example:

```js
const svgBox = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");

svgBox.setAttribute('height', 150);
svgBox.setAttribute('width', 800);
svgBox.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:purple;');

const div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]; // this does exist
div.appendChild(svgBox);
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

---